# How to display featured products through featured products block in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I have some products in Prestashop that I want to display on the homepage of my website as featured products. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the module `homefeatured`.

In its configuration, select the category containing the products you want to show in this block.